# Scopes en Javascript problema al ordenar Array

Tags: javascript, array, ordenamiento, scope

Lo que estoy haciendo funcionaria bien en Java y C pero en Javascript me esta tomando mi array del main y cuando lo ordeno en mi función **ordenarArray()** al parecer edita mi array principal, y eso no debería pasar, ese array ordenado debería quedarse local y no editar mi array del main, estas son las funciones:

```
function main() {

let array = pedirDatos();
showArray(array);
ordenarArray(array);

}

function pedirDatos() {
   var array = new Array();
   var elemento = null;
   while (elemento != "fin") {
      elemento = prompt("Ingrese el elemento: ");
      array.push(elemento);
      if(elemento=="fin"){
      array.pop();
         }
   }
   return array;
}

function ordenarArray(array) {
   document.write("</hr>");
   document.write("<h3> datos ordenados </h3>");
   array.sort();
   showArray(array);
}
function showArray(array) {
   document.write("<ul>")
   array.forEach((element, index) => {
      document.write("<li>" + element + "</li>");
   });
   document.write("</ul>")
}
```

parece como si le pasara el parámetro por puntero y referencia así como en C por que no se por que se edita, incluso probé usando otras variables para no hacerle sort al parámetro, igual pasaba lo mismo, cuando ordenaba el nuevo array se ordenaba el array del main también, esto nunca me había pasado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En Javascript cuando pasas un array como referencia. Cualquier cambio que hagas al array se lo harás al array orginal. Para evitar esto debes hacer una copia del array. Ejemplo

```
  function ordenarArray(array) {
   const temp = array.slice(); // el metodo slice crea una copia del array original
   document.write("</hr>");
   document.write("<h3> datos ordenados </h3>");
   temp.sort();
   showArray(temp);
}
```

Comment: Para complementar esta excelente respuesta, me parece adecuado mencionar que esto no pasa con valores primitivos, más info por si el usuario de la pregunta gusta indagar https://medium.com/laboratoria-developers/por-valor-vs-por-referencia-en-javascript-de3daf53a8b9

Comment: Exacto :) Gracias

Comment: En efecto, al parecer en Javascript los valores primitivos o variables de tipo primitivas al pasarlas por parámetro se pasan por valor osea solo se pasa una copia de estas, al contrario de las variables de tipo Object, Array y Function las cuales si las pasamos por parámetro se pasaran por referencia.

Comment: Esto no solo pasa con javascript. Si tu tomas una clase y la instancias en c# o Java y la pasas como parametro cualquier cambio se hara a la instanciacion original.